# Firebase Rules: Not working consistently

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm using a structure for saving the users friends in the realtime database like this:

```
friends
    $user_id:
        -$friend_id1
            -name: ""
            -id: ""
        -$friend_id2
(...)
```

My rules look like this:

```
"friends":{
     "$id": {
        ".read": "auth != null && $id === auth.uid",
        ".write": false,
      },
  },
```

Within my iOS App I can access the friends of others although I should not be able to do so.
Also this seems to mainly be an issue in one single view, since when I'm changing the

```
"read": false
```

I can still read this data in that specific view.
In all other views however I can not do that, although the code is nearly the same (except for observing (`.childAdded`) instead of (`.value`).

I´m calling

```
let friends_ref = Database.database().reference().child("friends").child(self.friend_id)
    friends_ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

    //CODE

})
```

Also, the time it takes to load the friends, so to get the callback, is very long taking even about >5 Seconds to get 5 friends.

How can this happen?

Best regards

Comment: I'm not seeing any code where you try to access other peoples friends. Also it is possible the data is still cached when you changed the rules so it will read from cache first (no rules on your cache because you already got the data).

Comment: Just changed the self.user_id to self.friend_id. This string is the uid of a friend of the currentUser, so I‘m trying to access his friends not my own. Regarding the cached data: I rebuild the app several times etc. and also it starts loading them again taking >5 seconds.

Comment: Your rules seem to be correct so I have no idea what the problem can be. Maybe it still uses some old rules? It can take a little while for newly implemented rules to take effect.

Comment: I thought so too. However, the rules have immediate impact on the observe(.childAdded) which is running simultanously in another view for my own friends. So I get an error immediately. Very strange... Do you have any idea on why it takes so long to load apart from the security rules problem?

Comment: Most likely as Andre says the unreadable data is coming from the cache. Uninstall and reinstall the app (not just rebuild it) to ensure the cache is clear.

Comment: Thank‘s! The issue with the rules is ok now. However, the request still often takes >5 seconds (to fetch the 5 friends from the friend). What could be the reason for that?